# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 received on Chinese Website that was working until July 25,2022 but has failed since

Tags: java, url

I support a ERP system that requires are China Site to update Exchange Rates at the end of the month.
A JAVA Class is ran everyday to extract those exchange rates from  http://www.pbc.gov.cn/zhengcehuobisi/125207/125217/125925/index.html

After July 25 2022 the routine returns java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://www.pbc.gov.cn/zhengcehuobisi/125207/125217/125925/index.html

This code was developed by one of our Chinese Employees that is no longer with us. I am not a JAVA programmer, so I am adept at debugging the code.

Here is the code - the error is generated on the conn.getInputStream

```
public static String sendPost(String url, String param) {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL realUrl = new URL(url);
            // 打开和URL之间的连接
            URLConnection conn = realUrl.openConnection();
            // 设置通用的请求属性
            conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
            //conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent",
                //    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");
            // 发送POST请求必须设置如下两行
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // 获取URLConnection对象对应的输出流
            out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            // 发送请求参数
            out.print(param);
            // flush输出流的缓冲
            out.flush();
            // 定义BufferedReader输入流来读取URL的响应
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
```

Here is how sendPost is called:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String s1 = ChnExchRate.sendPost("http://www.pbc.gov.cn/zhengcehuobisi/125207/125217/125925/index.html",null );
```

When I paste the offending URL in my browser I reach the website. I can see the exchange rates and can manually enter them in our system.

Comment: Nobody here can help you.  This is an error from the website saying it doesn't like the way your request is formatted, so something at their end has changed.  You will need to find someone who can talk to the website's admins or support staff and determine what has changed.  Did you try uncommenting the `user-agent` header?

Comment: (1) try 2022-12-29 ( http://www.pbc.gov.cn/zhengcehuobisi/125207/125217/125925/4749097/index.html ) ,(2) you can test by `wget http://www.pbc.gov.cn/zhengcehuobisi/125207/125217/125925/index.html` , and use notepad or gedit open downloaded index.html , it's all javascipt, It will ask you to enable JavaScript and then Refresh Page. You can use Firefox Web Devloper Tool , and open the page again. You will see 200, then 404. (3) This is not java code problem. (5) maybe try find other data provider url.